# Grabbing information from an html file

Tags: java

OK, I am trying to grab the data-title and href and assigning them to variables in java.

```
<tr class="pl-video yt-uix-tile " data-video-id="MBBWVgE0ewk" data-set-video-id="" data-title="Windows Command Line Tutorial - 1 - Introduction to the Command Prompt"><td class="pl-video-handle "></td><td class="pl-video-index"></td><td class="pl-video-thumbnail"><span class="pl-video-thumb ux-thumb-wrap contains-addto"><a href="/watch?v=MBBWVgE0ewk&amp;index=1&amp;list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDV6SnbINlVUd0o2xT4JbMu"
```

Comment: You say you are trying to do something. Show us what you have tried doing that didn't work.

Comment: @TheHeadRush OK, honestly I have no idea on going about this. I tried looking up tutorials and documentation about this, but didn't find anything that looked like what I wanted. I'd rather learn how to do it then just someone doing it for me, but I don't think anyone would answer if I just asked for a book or documentation on this.

Comment: What you want is a DOM parser. Java comes with a set of tools for this in the javax.xml.parsers package. Jsoup, recommended below, is a bit more user friendly but consumes more memory, at least in my experience.

Comment: @TheHeadRush Thanks I'll look into this package

Comment: Please try and add some code and more information. Are you running a java console and opening an html file using File? Is this J2EE? Did you confuse Java with JavaScript? Without a few more lines of text, all of the above are possible.

Comment: @RoyFalk Java JDK running with blueJ trying to get links from websites...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind including a dependency, there is a good library for this kind of things called [jsoup](http://jsoup.org).

```
String html = ...
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element tr = doc.select("tr").first();
Element link = tr.select("a").first();

String dataTitle = tr.attr("data-title");
String href = link.attr("href");
```

Comment: How exactly does this work and what if there is more than 1 of href or data-title?

Comment: Look at ***Solution*** section at http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html